# Rails adding devise new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add a new action in my devise registration controller but getting error routes not found.I haven't done this before so maybe I am making mistake.I am adding the index action on my registration controller.I have made a user model using devise.Getting error **No route matches [GET] "/users/registrations"** 
[registrations_controller]

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource
  def index
    @users=User.all
    redirect_to index_path
  end

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).permit(:attachment)
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :attribute
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

end
```

[routes]

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
        registrations: 'users/registrations'
        #get 'users/registrations'
      }

  devise_scope :user do
  get 'registrations/index', :action => 'index', :controller => 'registrations'
  end
```

Comment: did you change application layout ??

Comment: nope what changes i have to make?

Comment: are you using any custom layout?

Comment: no I am not using any custom layout

Comment: paste your html code for more clarification

Comment: which html code ???I have nothing my registration/index.html.erb.. I am getting error when defining routes

Comment: what you want to see my application.html.erb page?

Comment: what do you get for that route when you run `rake routes` ?

Comment: Also: can you please show us the full stacktrace from the server logs? You have provided just the error message, but usually when you get an error, you also get a whole slew of lines that are the names of files... the top 5-ish of those lines will be helpful to us because they outline which line of code caused the error... we can then look at what that line of code is doing to find out what is causing the error.

Comment: okay i am updating my code

Comment: If what you are looking to do is list all users then just create a `GET /users` route and create a UsersController instead. Its much simpler and cleaner. Don't try to stuff everything into the authentication system.